# How to use matplotlib to plot line charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I use pandas to read my csv file and turn two columns into arrays as independent/dependent variables respectively.
[the data reading, array-turning trans and value assign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Xho.png)

Then when I want to use matplotlib.pyplot to plot the line charts out, it turns out that 'numpy.ndarray' objects has no attribute 'find'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with your `dtypes`, assuming your data are in `df` check the `df.dtypes`. Columns you are trying to plot must be numeric (`float`, `int`, `bool`).

I guess that at least one of the columns you are plotting has `object` dtype, try to find out why (maybe missing values were read as some sort of string, or everything is just considered string) and convert it to correct type with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), i.e.

```
df['float_col'] = df['float_col'].astype(np.float64)
```

Edit:

If you are trying to plot date use, make sure that dtype is actually a date i.e. `datetime64[ns]` and use `matplotlib`s dedicated method [`plot_date`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date)

Comment: Thanx for your prompt answering and sharing. and the problem is dtype. The thing is that, I want to plot a line char whose x axes is date, (str I guess), and y axes is the discrete rate (float I guess). How can I plot it out with pyplot?

Comment: maek sure your dtype is not object but some sort of `datetime`, i.e. `datetime64` or `M<8`. Then use `matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date`